# How do I detect updates with a manually deployed ClickOnce using mage?

Tags: c#, .net, clickonce, mage

So I followed the instructions [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc3tc5xx.aspx) for manually deploying a clickonce application and I finally got things to work, but after incrementing the revision number and redeploying, I found that launching the installed application does not automatically update itself to the newest version.  Currently, my deployed folder structure is like this:

- foo.application
- Foo

  - foo.exe
  - foo.exe.manifest

What am I missing to have it automatically update itself similar to a ClickOnce publish from Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  Turns out that you have to do a few things different here:

1. You cannot just generate a new deployment file each time.  You have to update your existing one.
2. You have to manually set the `<beforeApplicationStartUp />` node since mage does not support this setting.

So what I ended up doing was first checking my remote deployment directory to see if I already have a deployment manifest, and if I did, I'd copy it over to my build server and call mage -Update and supply the new version number with -Version.  To force the update instead of prompting, you have to also supply -MinVersion and set it to the same value as -Version.  Before signing the updated deployment (or the first one if you haven't already deployed), I updated the file with the following powershell:

```
$content = Get-Content ".\${assemblyName}.application"
$content | % { $_.Replace('<expiration maximumAge="0" unit="days" />', '<beforeApplicationStartup />') } | Set-Content ".\${assemblyName}.application"
```

With this, I finally have all the parameters correct and can sign the deployment manifest and copy everything back.

Answer (score 2):

```
1) Open your project's properties in Visual Studio
2) Go to the Publish item
3) Click the Updates... button
4) Check "the application should check for updates"
5) Check "Before the application starts"
6) Check the Specify minimum required version for this application and make sure that the minimum version is set.
```

Using this means that the minimum version needs updated every time a new version is built if you are automatically incrementing your build #s, but it will force newly launched clients into upgrading. Existing open client application will notify user of the update, but not force them.

For MAGE, you should be using the -mv switch to specify that the current version is the required version. Please refer to Microsoft's [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acz3y3te(v=vs.110).aspx) on the matter.

Comment: I'm not publishing with Visual Studio.

Comment: @Lunyx Appended a comment for MAGE